# Getting a canvas element to move while holding down a key then stop when letting go

Tags: javascript, keydown, keyup

http://jsfiddle.net/genome314/4Hm8X/

**Problem with code:** If you hold down an arrow key and look at the console - the keyup is firing after every keydown. Additionally the object stops moving after holding down the arrow keys.

**Why this is a problem in this context:** I want the square to move every time the arrow keydown is fired, then for it to stop when keyup is fired.

**Desired effect**: I want to hold down a key to move the box, then for it to stop moving when I let go of the key.

- Is this achievable? If so, approximately how? If not, is there an alternative method for registering the direction?

For the record I don't want to use Jquery. Thanks for any tips or suggestions.

Javascript

```
keyLeft = 0;
keyRight = 0;
keyNorth = 0;
keyBot = 0;
var interval;
var c = 0;

window.onload=function(){
    addButton.addEventListener
        ('click',function(){addRowCell("table1")},false);
    removeButton.addEventListener
        ('click',function(){deleteRowCell("table1")},false);
    stopButton.addEventListener('click',stop,false);
    startButton.addEventListener('click',initiate,false);
}
//38 up
//37 left
//40 down
//39 right
document.onkeydown = function (e) {

    console.debug(e.keyCode, "down");
    console.debug(e.keyCode, "up");

    switch (e.keyCode){
        case 37:
            initiateLeft();
            break;
        case 38:
            initiateNorth();
            break;
        case 40:
            initiateBot();
            break;
        case 39:
            initiateRight();
            break;
        case 32:
            stop();
            break;
    }
}

function stop(){
    clearInterval(interval);
}
function initiateRight(){
    clearInterval(interval);
    interval = setInterval(right,100);
}
function initiateLeft(){
    clearInterval(interval);
    interval = setInterval(left,100);
}
function initiateNorth(){
    clearInterval(interval);
    c=0;
    interval = setInterval(north,100);
}
function initiateBot(){
    clearInterval(interval);
    interval = setInterval(bot,100);
}

function right(){
    var x = document.getElementById("counter");
    x.value = keyRight;
    var d = document.getElementById("canv1");
    var ctx = d.getContext("2d");
    var ctx1 = document.querySelector('#canv1').getContext('2d');
    ctx1.clearRect(0,0,100,100);    
    ctx.strokeRect(20+keyRight-keyLeft,20-keyNorth+keyBot,40,40);
    keyRight++;
}
function left(){
    var x = document.getElementById("counter");
    x.value = keyLeft;
    var d = document.getElementById("canv1");
    var ctx = d.getContext("2d");
    var ctx1 = document.querySelector('#canv1').getContext('2d');
    ctx1.clearRect(0,0,100,100);
    ctx.strokeRect(20+keyRight-keyLeft,20-keyNorth+keyBot,40,40);
    keyLeft++;
}
function north(){
    var x = document.getElementById("counter");
    x.value = keyNorth;
    var d = document.getElementById("canv1");
    var ctx = d.getContext("2d");
    var ctx1 = document.querySelector('#canv1').getContext('2d');
    ctx1.clearRect(0,0,100,100);
    keyNorth+=(10-c);
    c+=2;
    ctx.strokeRect(20+keyRight-keyLeft,20-keyNorth+keyBot,40,40);
    if(20-keyNorth == 20)
    clearInterval(interval);
}
function bot(){
    var x = document.getElementById("counter");
    x.value = keyBot;
    var d = document.getElementById("canv1");
    var ctx = d.getContext("2d");
    var ctx1 = document.querySelector('#canv1').getContext('2d');
    ctx1.clearRect(0,0,100,100);
    ctx.strokeRect(20+keyRight-keyLeft,20-keyNorth+keyBot,40,40);
    keyBot++;
}
```

HTML

```
<canvas id="canv1" width="300px" height="100px"></canvas>
<input id="counter" style="width:40px;"></input>
<div style="clear:left;">
Press spacebar to pause.<br>
```

Comment: @MindaugasVečkys I have added the HTML to the post if that's what you meant. If you're asking if I can add HTML to the code, yes that is fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I'm not doing your homework. If so you should feel guilty.

```
keyLeft = 0;
keyRight = 0;
keyNorth = 0;
keyBot = 0;
var interval;
var c = 0;



//38 up
//37 left
//40 down
//39 right
document.onkeydown = function (e) {

    console.debug(e.keyCode, "down");
    console.debug(e.keyCode, "up");

    switch (e.keyCode){
        case 37:
            initiateLeft();
            break;
        case 38:
            initiateNorth();
            break;
        case 40:
            initiateBot();
            break;
        case 39:
            initiateRight();
            break;
        case 32:
            stop();
            break;
    }
}

function stop(){

}
function initiateRight(){

    interval = setTimeout(right,100);
}
function initiateLeft(){

    interval = setTimeout(left,100);
}
function initiateNorth(){

    c=0;
    interval = setTimeout(north,100);
}
function initiateBot(){

    interval = setTimeout(bot,100);
}

function right(){

    var x = document.getElementById("counter");
    x.value = keyRight;
    var d = document.getElementById("canv1");
    var ctx = d.getContext("2d");
    var ctx1 = document.querySelector('#canv1').getContext('2d');
    ctx1.clearRect(0,0,100,100);    
    ctx.strokeRect(20+keyRight-keyLeft,20-keyNorth+keyBot,40,40);
    keyRight++;
}
function left(){
    var x = document.getElementById("counter");
    x.value = keyLeft;
    var d = document.getElementById("canv1");
    var ctx = d.getContext("2d");
    var ctx1 = document.querySelector('#canv1').getContext('2d');
    ctx1.clearRect(0,0,100,100);
    ctx.strokeRect(20+keyRight-keyLeft,20-keyNorth+keyBot,40,40);
    keyLeft++;
}
function north(){
    var x = document.getElementById("counter");
    x.value = keyNorth;
    var d = document.getElementById("canv1");
    var ctx = d.getContext("2d");
    var ctx1 = document.querySelector('#canv1').getContext('2d');
    ctx1.clearRect(0,0,100,100);
    keyNorth+=(10-c);
    c+=2;
    ctx.strokeRect(20+keyRight-keyLeft,20-keyNorth+keyBot,40,40);
}
function bot(){
    var x = document.getElementById("counter");
    x.value = keyBot;
    var d = document.getElementById("canv1");
    var ctx = d.getContext("2d");
    var ctx1 = document.querySelector('#canv1').getContext('2d');
    ctx1.clearRect(0,0,100,100);
    ctx.strokeRect(20+keyRight-keyLeft,20-keyNorth+keyBot,40,40);
    keyBot++;
}
```

Comment: lol, why do you think its homework xD I'm working on a little game for my website
Thanks for the tip though it works.

Comment: @Genome314 You never know. :) Glad to see it helped you.